# JNI: NoSuchFieldError error where clearly the field exists with correct signature

Tags: java, android, java-native-interface

I have a java class:

```
public class ClassOne implements Serializable {
    private String bField;
    private ArrayList<SomeClass> aField = new ArrayList<SomeClass>();
}
```

And I try to use it in C this way:

```
jlong
Java_ClassJNI_getArrayContent( JNIEnv* env, jobject this,
                                                jobject argument, jlong handle, jint isFirst) {

    jfieldID fid_bField, fid_aField;
    jclass cls = (*env)->GetObjectClass(env, argument); 
    fid_bField = (*env)->GetFieldID(env, cls, "bField", "Ljava/lang/String;");   
    fid_aField = (*env)->GetFieldID(env, cls, "aField", "Ljava.util.ArrayList;");

...
```

I get this error:

```
   java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: no field with name='aField' signature='Ljava.util.ArrayList;' in class LClassOne;
```

I have already cleaned and rebuilt the app and I keep getting this.
It's a code that has always work and somehow stopped, with no changes to the class at all. I did git reset to make sure I didn't screw up anywhere, but nada. It still throws the same error.

I did debug the app to make sure that the objects passed are correct, and they are. The class is correct, the `bField` is picked up correctly, but the `aField` throws an error.

I have tried changing `ArrayList<SomeClass>` to `ArrayList` but it has changed nothing.

I'm quite lost with that, do you have any idea why this would happen?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The descriptor should be "Ljava/util/ArrayList;". Slashes instead of dots.

Comment: God dammit.. you are right! Of course. Funny thing: it works with dots on one tablet [Android 7] and not on another [Android 4]